# How can I export metadata from Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, export, metadata

After I log my metadata (including the description and bin allocation) in Premiere Pro, I would like to export this to a table format (Excel or CSV).

Is there a possibility to do this directly or via a script that extracts this information from the project file?